# Forzar "numeros" Programa simple

Tags: c

Hola a todos nomas queria comentar tengo este programa sencillo, funciona pero cuando escribo una "letra" me arroja un numero - , como puedo corregir esto para forzar que escriba nomas "numeros" ?? o que mande un mensaje que pida que escribas un numero

```
#include<stdio.h>
 
int main() {
   int side, area;
 
   printf("\nEnter the Length of Side : ");
   scanf("%d", &side);
 
   area = side * side;
   printf("\nArea of Square : %d", area);
 
   return (0);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente función

```
int isdigit(int arg);
```

Esta función devuelve el numero si es un carácter numérico, y 0 si no es un carácter numérico.
Para poder utilizarla, debes incluir arriba (junto a #include <stdio.h>, una linea mas abajo) #include <ctype.h>

Para forzarlo puedes hacer un bucle con un if, que compruebe si el valor introducido es un digito, y si no que vuelva a ejecutarse.

```
bool esdigito=false;
int side, area;
while(esdigito==false){
     printf("\nEnter the Length of Side : ");
     scanf("%c", &side);
     if(isdigit(side)>0){
         esdigito=true
     }
}
area = side * side;
printf("\nArea of Square : %d", area);

return (0);
```

Así debería funcionarte, si tienes cualquier problema me comentas.

PD: recuerda poner el include que comento más arriba

Edit: Esto solo es válido si el número esta entre 0-9, si quieres que sea de 2 cifras qui tienes un ejemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void validar(char []);


void validar(char num[]){
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(num); i++)
    {
        if(!isdigit(num[i]) ) {
            printf("Ingrese un numero valido");
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char a[256];
    scanf("%s", a);
    validar(a);
    printf("blabla");
}
```

Comment: Esto no va a funcionar. `isdigit` comprueba si un caracter es un dígito numérico (acepta `int` porque usa ASCII extendido). Tu no le estás pasando un caracter sino un entero. Para que funcionase tu ejemplo tendrías que leer un `char` (`scanf("%c")`). Piensa que un `int` únicamente puede guardar enteros, aunque hagas `int var = 'c';`, en `var` seguirá habiendo un entero. Las variables no son polimórficas

Comment: Si, lo que comenta eferion es cierto, igualmente puedes usar la funcion isDigit, recogiendo un string, recorriendolo y validando uno a uno con la funcion isdigit, esto en caso de que te interese que sea un int de mas de 1 cifra, si solo te interesa que sea de 1, valdria con recoger en vez de con %d con %c.

Comment: El ejemplo debe ir _en tu respuesta_, no en un enlace externo. Recuerda que la respuesta debe ser de utilidad no solo para el autor de la pregunta, sino también para los demás miembros de la comunidad (es por eso que también se deben evitar los saludos y demás al preguntar/responder). Lee [answer].

Comment: Gracias a todos y por ponerme esos comentarios y ejemplos. Espero algun dia apoyar yo a alguien !

Answer (score 0):

Puedes validar si el valor que introduces por teclado es númerico mediante:

```
  if (scanf("%d", &side) == 1) {
```

Por lo tanto tu código sería:

```
#include<stdio.h>
 
int main() {
   int side, area;
 
   printf("\nEnter the Length of Side : ");
 
  if (scanf("%d", &side) == 1) { //Valida si el valor es númerico
     area = side * side;
     printf("\nArea of Square : %d", area);
  }else{
    printf("\nDebe escribir un valor númerico!");
  }
  
   return (0);
}
```

Comment: Gracias este me sirvio a la perfeccion!